# Full network forwarder with linux

Tags: linux, networking, forwarding

I want to use a linux machine as a full network forwader.

Target "physical" architecture :

- machineA is connected to network1 with its own addressing plan
- machineB is connected to network2 with its own addressing plan
- forwarder is connected to both

`[machineA] <---- net1 ----> [Forwarder] <---- net2 ----> [machineB]`

When machineA sends network traffic to Forwarder, I want all that traffic to be redirected to machineB (all of it : tcp, udp, icmp... every port, every protocol, ipv6...), and I want responses from machine B to be redirected to machineA as well.
The goal is to NAT all the queries (whatever the protocol) initiated by machineA, and do the same for responses from machineB. I want machineA know only the forwarder and think there is no machineB.

I managed to forward some ports with iptables but I cannot make it work for all network traffic

Any idea on what I can do to make this working with simple tools ?

**Note:** I don't think this is bridging, as I want requests from machineA to be addressed to the Forwarder : machineA does not know any other network than its own

Thanks in advance,
DJ

Comment: After reading a bit on the differences between bridging and routing you can probably more clearly define what exactly you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a router. The action it does is in fact called forwarding, enable packet forwarding on the device in between.

Comment: Hello John, thank you for your answer. 
I configured some routers and firewalls some time ago, and as far as I remembre, I had to configure one NAT line for every service I wanted to "hide"

I managed to forward packets on my linux machine, but only on specific ports, for example : 
```iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination <machineB>:80```

The issue I face is : can I do it for every protocol/port without having one iptables line per protocol/port ?

Comment: Your question didn't say you needed a NAT function, please edit it to add that requirement.

Comment: You are right, I though it was intended when I said "make machineA think there is no machineB" but I should have been more specific

Comment: IPv6 doesn't need NAT at all. So yes, you should have been specific that you wanted a v4 NAT function.  NAPT needs some port mapping scheme, so I don't have a transparent solution for you there.

Comment: Alright, I'll keep looking for other (commercial ?) solutions. Thanks for taking some time and answering me.